# Arranging books where specific genres must stay together

Tags: permutations, combinations

a student has 13 books:

5 mystery,

6 science fiction,

2 non-fiction.

how many ways can the books be positioned on a shelf if books must stay with their genre?

i thought it would be ${13!\over5!6!2!}$ but if the books "must stay with their genre" is that still right?

or would it be something like $3!5!6!2!$

im getting confused by the wording

Comment: The number $$\frac{13!}{5!6!2!}$$ represents the number of distinguishable arrangements of the word $$MMMMMSSSSSSNN$$ rather than the number of ways of arranging five distinct mysteries, six distinct science fiction books, and two non-fiction books on a shelf when books of the same genre are grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

Try to organize it as if you had to do it in reality :first , you arrange the sections, then the books within the sections

On your shelf, you have $3$ sections : Mystery, SF, and non-SF. You have $3!$ ways to arrange the sections.
For the Mystery section, you have $5!$ ways to organize your books, $6!$ for the SF section, and $2!$ for the non-SF.

That gives you a total of $$3!5!6!2!$$